# Inductive proof that ${2n\choose n}=\sum{n\choose i}^2.$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, induction, summation

I would like to prove inductively that $${2n\choose n}=\sum_{i=0}^n{n\choose i}^2.$$

I know a couple of non-inductive proofs, but I can't do it this way. The inductive step eludes me. I tried naively things like $${2n+2\choose n+1}={2n+2\over n+1}{2n+1\choose n}=2\cdot {2n+1\over n+1}{2n\choose n},$$

But I don't think it can lead me anywhere. I would like the proof to be as simple as possible.

Comment: This is a special case of [Chu-Vandermonde identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu-Vandermonde_identity). Sometimes a proof by induction might be easier if you prove a more general result. Although I am not sure whether it helps in this case.

Comment: I'll add a link to [another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148583/combinatorial-proof-of-summation-of-sum-k-0n-n-choose-k2-2n-choose), where a combinatorial proof is given.

Comment: This result is formulated too narrowly to have much chance of a inductive proof: knowing something about just the central binomial coefficients is insufficient in the induction because you don't have a useful recurrence realtion for just the central binomial coefficients. However, proving as Martin Sleziak suggested Chu-Vandermonde by induction (using Pascal's recurence) is a piece of cake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Martin Sleziak and Marc van Leeuwen's comments, I've found [this inductive proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/219938/23371) of Vandermonde's identity. (On this very site.)

Answer (score 7):

Split the $2n$ elements into two groups of size $n$
Then the no. of ways of choosing $n$ from the $2n$ is the no. of ways of choosing $i$ from the **1st** and $n-i$ from the **2nd** and letting $i$ vary.

Comment: How is this an inductive proof?