# combinatorial proof of Vandermonde's Identity

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing

So I can not figure out the combinatorial proof for Vandermonde's Identity for the example 
$\sum_{i=0}^k \binom {k} {i}^2 = \binom {2k} {k}$
Any help would be appreciated.

Figured it out, thanks :)

Comment: There’s one in [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Combinatorial_proof).

Comment: I'm sorry the post I selected is not the right one, I did not see the "inductive proof", maybe [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404715/how-to-get-n-choose-02n-choose-12n-choose-22-cdotsn-choose-n?lq=1) provides a combinatorial proof

Comment: @Haris: The excellent answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91457/combinatorial-interpretation-for-the-identity-sum-limits-i-binommi-binomn) may also be useful.