# What is the multiplication of $\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} \cdot {n \choose k}$ in terms of $n \choose k$

Tags: factorial

I know that ${n \choose k}$ $ = $ ${n \choose n-k}$ $ = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!(k)!}$, so I would write $$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} \cdot {n \choose k} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n!}{(n-k)!(k)!} \cdot \frac{n!}{(n-k)!(k)!} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(n!)^2}{((n-k)!(k)!)^2}$$
however from this point I do not know how to get it in terms of ${n \choose k}$. My book claims that this is equal to ${2n \choose n}$, but I can not see the connection between the two. Even when I write out ${2n \choose n}$, I do not see anything that is connection these two.
$${2n \choose n} = \frac{2n!}{(2n-n)!(n)!} = \frac{2n!}{(n)!(n)!} = \frac{2n!}{((n)!)^2}$$

edit: Indeed the book claims indeed that $\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} \cdot {n \choose k} = {2n \choose n}$ what has been suggested in the comments

Comment: Certainly not. Could you give a more verbatim copy of the book's claim? Could it be $$\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}^2={2n\choose n}$$?

Comment: What exactly does your book claim? That ${n \choose k} \cdot {n \choose k} = {2n \choose n}$?

Comment: The square of that term?

Comment: I think you mean $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}^2=\binom{2n}{n}$ if I'm not mistaken. If you mean this, you can find the proof [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/combinatorics/AnotherBinomialIdentity.shtml).

Comment: Do you mean $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k}^2$? If yes, then the book is true.

Comment: @UmbQbify-Key20- You put a bracket instead of a parenthesis near the end.

Comment: @Aiden Chow, yeah, I noticed that. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed the question was misformulated. I have edited just now. Thank you

Comment: Since @AidenChow provided the proof the question has been answered. thanks everyone

Comment: This has actually been asked before. Look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690076/proof-of-a-binomial-identity-sum-k-0n-n-choose-k-2-2n-choose-n/690086) for more proofs.