# What is the proof that the two below are equal?

Tags: binomial-theorem

Can you help me to prove the following equality ?

[image]

Comment: You didn't tell us about your background of this?

Comment: Well, welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange?  Maybe you need some help so this won't be closed.

Comment: Good idea!  Also watch out for the above.

Comment: also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373122/sum-of-square-binomial-coefficients)

Comment: Good call there.

Comment: Be more careful next time!  Some questions are duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proof of it is on Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Series_involving_binomial_coefficients).

Just for kicks, here's a combinatorial proof.  The right hand side is the number of ways to choose $n$ objects from a set of $2n$ objects.

If we split up the $2n$ objects as such: $1,2,\ldots,n | n+1, \ldots, 2n $, then we see that in order to pick $2n$ objects in total, we have to pick $k$ from the first $n$, and $n-k$ from the second set of $n$.  Summing over $k$ yields $$ \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{n - k} = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2 $$

Since the two values count the same thing, they must be equal.

Answer (score 2):

Let us first prove the Vandermonde identity : $\forall\left(n,m,k\right)\in\mathbb{N}^{3}$
 $$\sum_{j=0}^{k}\begin{pmatrix}m\\
j
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}n\\
k-j
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}m+n\\
k
\end{pmatrix}\,\,\,\,\,\left(1\right).$$

We have for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$
 $$\sum_{k=0}^{m+n}\begin{pmatrix}m+n\\
k
\end{pmatrix}x^{k}=\left(1+x\right)^{m+n}=\left(1+x\right)^{m}\left(1+x\right)^{n}=\left(\sum_{j=0}^{m}\begin{pmatrix}m\\
j
\end{pmatrix}x^{j}\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}\begin{pmatrix}n\\
j
\end{pmatrix}x^{k}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{m+n}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{k}\begin{pmatrix}m\\
j
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}n\\
k-j
\end{pmatrix}\right)x^{k},$$
 $$\begin{pmatrix}m+n\\
k
\end{pmatrix}x^{k}=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\begin{pmatrix}m\\
j
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}n\\
k-j
\end{pmatrix}x^{k}.$$
 For $x=1$
 , one obtains the result.

Then, for $m=k=n$
  in $\left(1\right)$
 , it comes

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\begin{pmatrix}n\\
k
\end{pmatrix}^{2}=\begin{pmatrix}2n\\
n
\end{pmatrix}.$$