# How to show inductively that $(2n)! > (n!)^2$

Tags: inequality, induction, factorial

So far I have:

Base case: $$ n = 1 : (2(1))! > (1!)^2$$
$$  2! > 1!^2$$
$$2 > 1$$
Induction step: Assume this is true for some $n > 1$
Let n = p + 1
$$(2(p+1))! > ((p+1)!)^2$$
$$(2p)!(2p+1)(2p+2) > ((p+1)!)^2$$
$$(2p)!>\frac{((p+1)!)^2}{(2p+1)(2p+2)}$$
Now I add 1 to the smaller term in the demoninator, for cancellation purposes which makes the RHS smaller so inequality still holds.

$$(2p)!>\frac{(p!)^2(p+1)^2}{(2p+2)(2p+2)}$$
$$(2p)!>\frac{(p!)^2}{4}$$
Now I am stumped on how to get rid of the extra 4 in the denominator.

Comment: Inductively? Would be easier to note that $\binom{2n}{n} > 1 $, as long as $n\ge 1$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Would you say ${2n \choose n} \gt 1$ since there are at least two ways of choosing $n$ objects from $2n$ (e.g. choose the first $n$ or the last $n$, and these are different choices when $n \ge 1$)?

Comment: Regardless of which answer best suits your purposes, please note the point in Mark Bennet's. Your calculation is backwards from the direction it needs to go. Proofs do not follow the order "conclusion $\implies$ known". They follow the order "known $\implies$ conclusion". In the induction step, you know that $(2p)! > (p!)^2$. You need to start with that, and proceed to $(2(p+1))! > ((p+1)!)^2$.

Comment: Here is a stronger inequality: [Prove that $2^n(n!)^2 \leq (2n)!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1264448#1264458)

Answer (score 14):

Use
$$(2n)! = n! (n+1)(n+2)\cdots(2n)> n! \cdot 1\cdot 2 \cdots n = (n!)^2.$$

Alternatively, if you know binomial coefficients,
$$
(2n)! = \binom{2n}{n} (n!)^2 > (n!)^2,
$$
since $\binom{2n}{n}$ is an integer $> 1.$

Comment: Thank you. This was much simpler than anything I was thinking, and very clearly true!

Answer (score 7):

By the inductive hypothesis we have $(2n)! \geq (n!)^2$, we need to show that $(2n+2)! \geq ((n+1)!)^2$ so we need 
\begin{eqnarray*}
(2n+2)(2n+1)  \geq (n+1)^2 \\
3n^2+4n+1 \geq 0 
\end{eqnarray*}
which is obviously true.

Answer (score 6):

You are arguing the wrong way. If you start with $$(2n)!\gt (n!)^2$$ and multiply this by $(2n+2)(2n+1)$ you get $$(2(n+1))!\gt(2n+2)(2n+1)(n!)^2\gt((n+1)!)^2$$leaving you some details to fill in.

The way you are arguing at the moment attempts to deduce the result for $n$ from the result for $n+1$.

Note also that if induction is not required, the fact that the binomial coefficient $\binom {2n}n$ is a positive integer does the job. There are also various ways of proving that $\binom nr$ is a positive integer for $0\le r \le n$ including some quite simple induction methods, which would then give the result you want as a special case.

Answer (score 5):

$(2(p+1))!=(2p+2)(2p+1)(2p)!>2(p+1)(2p+1)(p!)^{2}$, now
\begin{align*}
2(p+1)(2p+1)(p!)^{2}-((p+1)!)^{2}&=[2(2p+1)p!-(p+1)!](p+1)!\\
&=[2(2p+1)-(p+1)]p!(p+1)!\\
&=(3p+1)p!(p+1)!>0
\end{align*}

Comment: I think it's easier to write:

$$ \ldots (2p+2)(2p+1)(p!)^2 > (p+1)(p+1)(p!)^2 = ((p+1)!)^2 $$

Comment: Yes, just missed that better observation, thanks.