# Closed form of Sum of Squared Binomial Coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, binomial-coefficients, proof-explanation, gamma-function

I'm reading a paper, it states that following is true:
$$\frac{1}{2}((C_{0}
^{n})^{2}+(C_{1}^{n})^{2}+(C_{3}^{n})^{2}...+(C_{n}^{n})^{2})=\frac{2^{2n}(n-\frac{1}{2})!}{2\sqrt{\pi}n!}\leq \frac{2^{2n}}{2\sqrt{\pi}}$$
where n is positive integer.

My question is: how to achieve $\frac{2^{2n}(n-\frac{1}{2})!}{2\sqrt{\pi}n!}$?
I guess it needs helps of following:

1. $(C_{0}^{n})^{2}+(C_{1}^{n})^{2}+(C_{3}^{n})^{2}...+(C_{n}^{n})^{2})=C_{n}^{2n}$
2. $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+n)=\frac{(2n)!}{4^{n}n!}\sqrt{\pi}=\left(
   \begin{array}{ll}n-\frac{1}{2}\\n\end{array} \right) n! \sqrt{\pi}$

Could any one tell me about how to do this? thanks

Answer (score 1):

The bracketed sum, that is, $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom {n}{k}^2 =\binom {2n}{n} $$ is called the central binomial coefficient. To see why this is so, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373122/sum-of-square-binomial-coefficients).

---

For the proof, see @robjohn's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58560/elementary-central-binomial-coefficient-estimates). Hope it helps.

Comment: Why it can be written as $\frac{2^{2n}(n-\frac{1}{2})!}{2\sqrt{\pi}n!}$?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for response, I come up with the answer, just some substitutions:

$$\frac{(2n)!}{4^{n}n!}\sqrt{\pi}=\frac{(n-\frac{1}{2})!}{n!(-\frac{1}{2})!}
 n! \sqrt{\pi}$$
$$\frac{(2n)!}{n!}=\frac{4^{n}(n-\frac{1}{2})!}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}$$
Where $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})=\sqrt{\pi}$
$$\frac{(2n)!}{n!}=\frac{4^{n}(n-\frac{1}{2})!}{\sqrt{\pi}}$$
Substitute $\frac{(2n)!}{n!}$ back to $\left(\begin{array}{ll} 2n\\n \end{array}\right)=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$:
$$\left(\begin{array}{ll} 2n\\n \end{array}\right)=\frac{4^{n}(n-\frac{1}{2})!}{\sqrt{\pi}n!}$$