# Calculating summation involving binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, double-sequence

$$\sum_{0<=i<j<=7} \sum_{}\binom{7}{i} \binom{7}{j}$$

I'm not aware how to we proceed with such summations what do they represent so any way  to teach me out this summation

Comment: The computation becomes easier if you use the $(7)$-th row of [Pascal's Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) (i.e. $\{1,7,21, \cdots\}$).  Then, if it were me, I would ignore any hidden meaning of the computation, avoid any attempt at elegance, and simply manually compute the double summation that will end up having $(8 + 7 + \cdots + 2 + 1) = 28$ terms.  Each term will be the product of two numbers, where each number is taken from one of the elements in the 7th row of Pascal's triangle.

Comment: Re previous comment, you can use the distributive property as a minor shortcut.  That is (for example) $(a \times b) + (a \times c) + (a \times d) + (a \times e) = [a \times (b + c + d + e)].$

Comment: By the way, re my first comment, I misinterpreted the summation as $\cdots i \leq j\cdots$ rather than $\cdots i < j \cdots$.  Therefore, you only have $(7 + 6 + \cdots + 2 + 1) = 21$ terms.

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing.  It seems that $(7 + 6 + \cdots + 2 +1) = 28.$  *Go figure*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I just thought of a shortcut.

Consider $(1 + 7 + 21  + 35 + 35 + 21 + 7 + 1)\times (1 + 7 + 21  + 35 + 35 + 21 + 7 + 1).$

This product, which has $(64)$ terms, is equal to
$(2^7)^2 = (128)^2 = 16,384.$

This represents $i \in$ {$0,1,\cdots,7$} and $j \in$ {$0,1,\cdots,7$}.

Deduct from this the $8$ times that $i = j$.  This is represented by

$(1^2 + 7^2 + 21^2 + 35^2 + 35^2 + 21^2 + 7^2 + 1^2)$

$= 2 \times (1^2 + 7^2 + 21^2 + 35^2) = 2 \times 1,716 = 3,432.$

$16,384 - 3,432 = 12,952$.

This represents the $(56)$ terms where 
$i \in$ {$0,1,\cdots,7$} and $j \in$ {$0,1,\cdots,7$}, 
and $i \neq j$.

This must be exactly double the sum, since by symmetry, each occurrence of $i < j$ is balanced by an occurrence of $i > j$.

Therefore the desired computation of the 28 terms is 
$\displaystyle \frac{12,952}{2} = 6,476.$

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a faster way to calculate user2661923’s solution.

The sum of 7 choose i from 0 to 7 is $(1+1)^7=2^7=128$.

The sum of 7 choose i squared is 14 choose 7=3432 (i from first 7, i not to choose from second 7).

This gives $(128^2-3432)/2=6476$

Comment: +1 : nice.  For those wanting to verify, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373122/sum-of-square-binomial-coefficients).

Answer (score 1):

Summations like this are funny-looking. I don't think we need two sigmas here.
$$\sum_{0\leq i<j\leq 7} \binom{7}{i} \binom{7}{j}.$$

I imagine we are talking about $i,j$ integers. First look inside the summation:

$$\binom{7}{i} \binom{7}{j}.$$

We will sum a certain collection of expressions like this. To evaluate just one of these, we need to know the values of integers $i$ and $j$.

Which pairs of integers $i,j$ will occur in the sum?

Those, and only those, satisfying $0\leq i<j\leq 7$.

This can be expressed as a double sum, similar to double integrals in calculus.

To separate into a double sum, you could note that $0\leq i\leq 6$.

Comment: I prefer two sigmas. Neat explanation tho

Comment: The two-sigma notation doesn't bother me. But in my mind, this is just an instance of $\sum_{t\,\in\,\Omega} a(t),$ where $\Omega$ is a set and $a$ is a given function.