# Calculate the sum of S.

Tags: summation

Consider $n\in\mathbb{N}.$ Find the sum of:$$S=\left(\dfrac{C_n^0}{1} \right)^2+\left(\dfrac{C_n^1}{2} \right)^2+\cdots+\left( \dfrac{C_n^n}{n+1}\right)^2$$

> I don't know how to solve it, i don't have any ideas, so i am very happy to hear from you. Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the notation $C_n^{j}$?

Comment: I think it is $C^1_n$ not $C^j_n$ :)

Comment: I think $C^j_n = {n \choose j}$, no?

Comment: I really understand, can you make it more cleary, I am very thank you.

Comment: You manually added spacing, writing "+\,...\,+".  But spacing is added automatically when using \dots or \ldots or \cdots, including spacing between the dots.  If you write "..." when using LaTeX in the usual way (as opposed to using it on web sites in the form of MathJax and the like), then when you write a,...,b you see $a,\text{...},b$ instead of $a,\ldots,b$ (which is coded as a,\ldots,b) or $a+\text{...}+b$ instead of $a+\cdots+b$.  I changed it to "+\cdots+$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thinking along the lines of integrating $(1+x)^n$, then dividing by $x$ and then integrating again. The value of the integral at $x=1$ should give the required sum. But running into some errors and short of time, so I'll just leave this here as an avenue to explore.

Comment: Is the 0 supposed to be below the 'n' in the choose function?

Answer (score 3):

**Outline**:
$$
\frac{{n \choose k}}{k+1} =\frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!(k+1)}=\frac{n!}{(k+1)!(n-k)!} = \frac{1}{n+1}\cdot {n+1 \choose k+1}
$$
so
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \Big(\frac{{n \choose k}}{k+1}\Big)^2 = \Big(\frac{1}{n+1}\Big)^2 \sum_{k=0}^n {n+1 \choose k+1}^2 
$$

Now, it is known that 
$$
\sum_{l=0}^{m} {m \choose l}^2 = {2m \choose m} 
$$
(you can do this inductively, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320348/inductive-proof-that-2n-choose-n-sumn-choose-i2)). From here... can you finish?

Comment: I don't know what does the $\left(n\choose k\right)$ mean, can you help me to explanit it, thank you.

Comment: ${n \choose k} = \frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!}$ which is what I believe you mean by $C^k_n$, right?