# How to prove that $\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}^2 =\binom{2n}{n}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, binomial-coefficients

How can I prove that $\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}^2 =\binom{2n}{n}$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Induction on $n$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inductive proof that ${2n\choose n}=\sum{n\choose i}^2.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320348/inductive-proof-that-2n-choose-n-sumn-choose-i2). There's also this older question which is similar but with a combinatorial focus: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148583/combinatorial-proof-of-summation-of-sum-limits-k-0n-n-choose-k2-2n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $n$ girls and $n$ boys. We want to choose a n-person from them to make a team. We will prove the statement by double-counting this amount.

---

---

Clearly we have $C(n,2n)$ choices.

---

---

On the other hand we can assume that there are $i$ boys in the team, where $0 \leq n$, choose $i$ arbitrary but fix it, we have $C(i,n)$ choices for chosing boys, and $C(n-i,n)$ choices for chosing girls, so we have:

$C(n,2n) = \sum_{i=0}^n C(i,n)C(n-i,n)$,

but notice that we have $C(i,n)=C(n-i,n)$. So the disired equality holds:

$C(n,2n) = \sum_{i=0}^n C(i,n)C(i,n)$.

Comment: I can't seem to get why it is **sum** of choosing i boys out of n multiplied by n-i girls.

Comment: Every team you have choosen, it may contains exactly $0$ boys, or it may contains exactly $1$ boys, or it may contains exactly $2$ boys,....,  or it may contains exactly $n-1$ boys, or it may contains exactly $n$ boys.

Comment: In any of the above cases, respectively; we have exactly $n$ girls in the team, or exactly $n-1$ girls in the team, or exactly $n-2$ girls in the team, ..., or exactly $1$ girls in the team, or exactly $0$ girls in the team.

Comment: Aha, I think I get it now. It's like a further partitioning to boys and girls, but the ways it can become are many, so I guess we are using rule of sum here.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite one $\binom{n}{i}$ factor as $\binom{n}{n-i}$, then note both sides count ways to choose $n$ elements from a set of size $2n$.