# Sum of products of binomial coefficients: $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{19}\binom{18}k\binom{20}k$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Please help me find the sum given below

$\sum_{k=0}^{19}\binom{18}{k}\binom{20}{k}$

First I used formula $\binom{m}{k}=\binom{m-1}{k}+\binom{m-1}{k-1}$  twice and got
$\sum_{k=0}^{19}\binom{18}{k}\binom{20}{k}=\sum_{k=0}^{19}\binom{18}{1k}\cdot \left ( \binom{19}{k}+\binom{19}{k-1} \right )=\sum_{k=0}^{19}\binom{18}{k}\cdot\left ( \binom{18}{k}+2\binom{18}{k-1}+\binom{18}{k-2} \right )$

Now have no idea what to do with that

Comment: take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)

Comment: ?? How would I use this ?

Comment: You could check this post: [How to prove Vandermonde's Identity: $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{R}{k}\binom{M}{n-k}=\binom{R+M}{n}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/337923) (And also some of the [questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/337923).) Probably also this post might give you some idea how to proceed: [Inductive proof that ${2n\choose n}=\sum{n\choose i}^2.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/320348). (Again, the [questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/320348) might be useful too.)

Comment: I will just add that this post has some useful advice on searching on this site: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)

Answer (score 2):

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{19}\binom{18}{k}\binom{20}{k}}
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{18}\binom{18}{k}\binom{20}{k}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{18}\binom{18}{18-k}\binom{20}{k}\tag{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{38}{18}=33\,578\,000\,610}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we omit the index $k=19$, since $\binom{p}{q}=0$ if $q>p$.
- In (2) we apply the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.
- In (3) we apply  *[Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_identity)*.

Answer (score 1):

Your sum is equal to $c_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{18}{k} \binom{20}{n-k}$ for $n=20.$ Note that $c_n$ is the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1+x)^{18} (1+x)^{20}.$