# Generalized Vandermonde's identity

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, summation, binomial-coefficients

Can you please provide a reference to the following generalization of Vandermonde's identity?

Given a positive integer $k$ and nonnegative integers $n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_k$ and $m$, it holds that $$\sum_{i_1+i_2+\cdots+i_k=m} \binom{n_1}{i_1} \binom{n_2}{i_2} \cdots \binom{n_k}{i_k} = \binom{n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_k}{m}.$$ The proof is well-known and based on the idea of counting in two different ways the coefficient of $x^m$ in the polynomial $(1+x)^{n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_k}$.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1131450/203995) you can find a formulation and a sketch of a proof.

Comment: @Pp. Your link points to _this_ thread. In any case, I don't need a proof, but a (standard) reference to the result (say, a book or an article published in a mainstream journal).

Comment: I would try searching in A=B or Concrete Mathematics.

Comment: As far as I can say, it is neither there, nor in Riordan's book, nor in Gould's tables, nor in Stanley's two volumes.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Chu%E2%80%93Vandermonde_identity) alleges the [Roth-Hagen identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3572304) generalizes this.

Answer (score 1):

The generalised identity is stated without proof in Concrete Mathematics, exercise 5.62. The proof technique that you mention is used for the ungeneralised Vandermonde identity in section 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{array}{l}
 \sum\limits_{i_1  + i_2  +  \cdots  + i_k  = m} {\left( \begin{array}{c}
 n_1  \\ 
 i_1  \\ 
 \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{c}
 n_2  \\ 
 i_2  \\ 
 \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{c}
 n_3  \\ 
 i_3  \\ 
 \end{array} \right) \cdots \left( \begin{array}{c}
 n_k  \\ 
 i_k  \\ 
 \end{array} \right)}  =  \\ 
  = \sum\limits_{i_1  + i_2  = m - \left( {i_3  \cdots  + i_k } \right)} {\left( {\left( \begin{array}{c}
 n_1  \\ 
 i_1  \\ 
 \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{c}
 n_2  \\ 
 i_2  \\ 
 \end{array} \right)} \right)\left( \begin{array}{c}
 n_3  \\ 
 i_3  \\ 
 \end{array} \right) \cdots \left( \begin{array}{c}
 n_k  \\ 
 i_k  \\ 
 \end{array} \right)}  =  \\ 
  = \sum\limits_{i_3  = m - \left( {i_4  \cdots  + i_k } \right)} {\left( {\left( \begin{array}{c}
 n_1  + n_2  \\ 
 m - \left( {i_3  \cdots  + i_k } \right) \\ 
 \end{array} \right)} \right)\left( \begin{array}{c}
 n_3  \\ 
 i_3  \\ 
 \end{array} \right) \cdots \left( \begin{array}{c}
 n_k  \\ 
 i_k  \\ 
 \end{array} \right)}  =  \\ 
  =  \cdots  \\ 
 \end{array}