# How do I prove that $\sum\limits_{r=0}^k \binom{m}{r}\binom{n}{k-r} = \binom{m+n}{k}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I have tried the following: Expanding the coefficients and i end up with something like this: $\sum\limits_{r=0}^k \binom{m}{r}\binom{n}{k-r} = \frac{m!}{(m-r)!r!} \frac{n!}{(n-k+r)!(k-r)!}$ and then expand the sum which does not seem to be very useful. I have also been thinking about use the Pascal's triangle in my proof but i haven't figured out how to do it in a way that does not look so sloppy. Any tips will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this same question has been posted several times.  This is Vandermonde's identity.

Comment: There's something wrong with the RHS of your equation.

Comment: There is a standard counting argument: to pick a $k$ subset out of a set of $m+n$ elements, choose for each $r$, an $r$ subset of the first $m$ elements and a $k-r$ subset of the remaining $n$ elements.

Comment: @mathlove : You link to a request for an algebraic rather than a combinatorial proof.  That's not quite identical to this present question.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Nowhere in the question is a combinatorial proof asked for. It simply ask "How do I prove this" so imo the duplicate it fine unless OP adds more info about what he wants.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks a lot, i did not know this was known as the Vandermonde's identity. That makes research about this problem a lot easier.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: For your second comment, I didn't think so. And I agree with Winther. Anyway, OP seemed to approve a duplicate vote.

Comment: @Winther : You missed the fact that this present question does _not_ ask for an algebraic proof, so it would admit other answers.

Comment: @MichaelHardy If you want to find a better duplicate that should not be hard, this question has been asked 100 times so there are [plenty of duplicates](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Vandermonde%27s+identity) to choose from.

Answer (score 3):

The right side is the number of ways to choose a subcommittee of size $k$ from a committee of $m$ Democrats and $n$ Republicans.

$\dbinom{m}{r}\dbinom{n}{k-r}$ is the number of ways to choose $r$ Democrats and $k-r$ Republicans from that committee.  The number $r$, the number of Democrats, plainly has to be at least $0$ and not more than $k$.  So $k-r$, the number of Republicans, must also be in that range.  Now think about what it means to take the sum.

Answer (score 1):

choosing $k$ people from $m+n$ people $=\binom{m+n}{k}$
now suppose :choosing $k$ people from $m\text{ people} + n\text{ people}$
choose $0$ from $m$ , $k$ from $n$
choose $1$ from $m$ , $k-1$ from $n$
choose $2$ from $m$ , $k-2$ from $n$
${}\qquad\vdots$
  in left hand we have :$$ \binom{m}{0}\binom{n}{k}+\binom{m}{1}\binom{n}{k-1}+\binom{m}{2}\binom{n}{k-2}+\cdots+\binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{k-k}$$   and in the right hand we have $$ \binom{m+n}{k}$$
so
they must be equal

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Develop both sides of $\,(x+y)^m(x+y)^n=(x+y)^{m+n}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Pascal's Triangle, then I would suggest induction on $n$.

In the induction step, working right to left, first use the triangle property to split $\binom{m+n}{k}$ into $\binom{m+(n-1)}{k-1}+\binom{m+(n-1)}{k}$, then apply the induction hypothesis to each of these binomial coeffients. Finally collect terms with the same $\binom{m}{r}$ and use the triangle again to combine their coefficients.