# How to prove that the sum of squared binomials equals $\binom{2n}{n}$

Tags: summation, induction, binomial-coefficients

I've stumbled upon this lemma a few times in my textbook:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\begin{pmatrix}n\\k\end{pmatrix}^2=\begin{pmatrix}2n\\n\end{pmatrix}$$
I've been trying to prove it, but I simply can't seem to see a connection. I've been trying to use proof by induction, but I can't express the statement for $n+1$ via the statement for $n$.

How do I prove it?

Comment: You mean $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}^{\color{Red}{2}}=\binom{2n}{n}$?

Comment: Please consider changing/editing the title.

Comment: or of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373122/sum-of-square-binomial-coefficients or of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320348/inductive-proof-that-2n-choose-n-sumn-choose-i2 or of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404715/how-to-get-n-choose-02n-choose-12n-choose-22-cdotsn-choose-n ...

Comment: I don't understand the reopen posts.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670672/binomial-coefficients-proof-sum-k-0n-n-choose-k-2-2n-choose-n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
{n \choose k} = {n \choose n-k}
$$
Then we can divide $2n$ objects into two groups. Form one group we choose $k$ from the other $n-k$ and we assuming all possibilities for $k$. Hence we get:
$$
{2n \choose n}=\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k} {n \choose n-k} = \sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}^2
$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\dbinom n k= \dbinom n {n-k}$, the identity
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k ^2 = \binom {2n} n
$$
is the same as
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k \binom n {n-k} = \binom {2n} n.
$$
So say a committee consists of $n$ Democrats and $n$ Republicans, and one will choose a subcommittee of $n$ members.  One may choose $k$ Democrats and $n-k$ Republicans in $\dbinom n k \cdot \dbinom n {n-k}$ ways.  The number of Democrats is in the set $\{0,1,2,\ldots,n\}$, thus ranging from all Republicans to all Democrats.  The sum then gives the total number of ways to choose $n$ out of $2n$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1+x)^{2n}$. We have
$$
(1+x)^{2n}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}x^k=(1+x)^n(1+x)^n=
\Big(\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^k\Big)\Big(\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}\Big).
$$
The coefficient of $x^n$ is equal to $\binom{2n}{n}$ in the left hand side.

The coefficient of $x^n$ is equal to $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}^{\!2}$ in the right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the following.

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\begin{pmatrix}n\\k\end{pmatrix}=(1+1)^n=2^n.$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\begin{pmatrix}n\\k\end{pmatrix}^2=\begin{pmatrix}2n\\n\end{pmatrix}$$

To prove the last inequality it suffice to calcuate the coefficient by $x^n$ at both sides of the equality

$$(1+x)^n(1+x)^n=(1+x)^{2n}.$$