# How do I show that $\sum_{k = 0}^n \binom nk^2 = \binom {2n}n$?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

$$\sum_{k = 0}^n \binom nk^2 = \binom {2n}n$$

I know how to "prove" it by interpretation (using the definition of binomial coefficients), but how do I *actually* prove it?

Comment: One common algebraic proof uses the fact that $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$ to reduce the problem to showing $\sum \binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{n-k}=\binom{2n}{n}$ and then observe that $\binom{2n}{n}$, the $n$-th coefficient of $(1+x)^{2n}=((1+x)^n)^2=(\sum \binom{n}{k}x^{k})^2$ is $\sum \binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{n-k}$.

Comment: @cjackal Thank you. Actually my interpretation is based on the fact that $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk \binom n{n-k}=\binom {2n}n$.

Comment: Well then what do you mean in saying "analytically"? I think generating functionology is usually considered as analytic...

Comment: @cjackal I think I mean algebraically, actually. I provided a physical interpretation, which I think is not analytical. I'll edit it.

Comment: You can have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670672/binomial-coefficients-proof-sum-k-0n-n-choose-k-2-2n-choose-n and
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404715/how-to-get-n-choose-02n-choose-12n-choose-22-cdotsn-choose-n (and other posts linked there). You can find several proofs there (induction, binomial theorem).

Comment: I see some discussion about it already, but what do you mean exactly with algebraically?

Comment: @EricS. But does it *really* matter? Actually I just wanted a *mathematical* proof in the sense that the proof is not merely a physical interpretation or one that is based on intuition.

Comment: @YuxiaoXie, well to me it doesn't matter at all, in the sense that I would just prove it by induction. But I was just wondering what is meant with an _algebraic_ proof...

Comment: @YuxiaoXie, returning to my previous comment; of course it matters. Asking specifically for an algebraic proof, implies proofs other than algebraic ones are not what you are looking for. Without a clear definition of what an algebraic proof even is, how do we know what proofs we can and cannot provide you with?!

Comment: @EricS. Then I think I'll delete that word to avoid confusion. This is open to all kinds of proofs that are rigorous and well based.

Comment: @YuxiaoXie. Thank you. I hope I didn't come across as whiney or anything, I was generally interested in the meaning of algebraic in this sense. Further, I think it's an interesting question `:)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure if you consider this proof analytic: Write $D = d/dx$. From the [Leibniz rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule), we have

\begin{align*}
\frac{(2n)!}{n!}
= D^n x^{2n} |_{x=1}
&= D^n (x^n \cdot x^n) |_{x=1} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} (D^k x^n)(D^{n-k} x^n) |_{x=1} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{n!}{(n-k)!} \frac{n!}{k!}.
\end{align*}

Then the identity follows by dividing both sides by $n!$ and simplifying it.

Answer (score 5):

## A combinatorial proof

How many ways can we pick $n$ objects from a selection of $2n$?

Consider the $2n$ objects to be $$(1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2), \dots, (n, 1), (n, 2)$$

Then the number of ways we can pick out $n$ of these is equal to the number of ways we can pick out $n$ conditioning on how many we select with second coordinate $1$.
That is, $$\sum_{k=0}^n \text{ways to select $k$ with $1$-coordinate} \times \text{ways to select $n-k$ with $2$-coordinate}$$

The summand is clearly $$\binom{n}{k} \times \binom{n}{n-k}$$
But that is $$\binom{n}{k} \times \binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{k}^2$$

Comment: This is actually the same as my interpretation. But, seriously, can it really be regarded as a proof? Since this method is developed using mainly words, it doesn't seem as reliable or rigorous.

Comment: @YuxiaoXie If you preferred, I could express it as the equality of the cardinalities of certain sets by providing bijections between them. I won't do that because it's tedious.

Answer (score 4):

**A Complex-Analytic (~Algebraic) Proof**

For $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\,\binom{n}{k}\,\frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{k+1}}=\frac{(1+z)^n}{z}\,\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\,\binom{n}{k}\,\frac{1}{z^k}=\frac{(1+z)^n}{z}\,\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)^n=\frac{(1+z)^{2n}}{z^{n+1}}$.  Thus, if $\gamma$ is a curve that counterclockwise wounds around the origin once, then
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\,\binom{n}{k}^2=\sum_{k=0}^n\,\binom{n}{k}\,\binom{n}{k}&=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\,\binom{n}{k}\,\left(\frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\,\oint_{\gamma}\,\frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{k+1}}\,\text{d}z\right)
\\&=\frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\,\oint_{\gamma}\,\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\,\binom{n}{k}\,\frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{k+1}}\text{d}z
\\&=\frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\,\oint_{\gamma}\,\frac{(1+z)^{2n}}{z^{n+1}}\text{d}z=\binom{2n}{n}\,.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

To prove binomial identities it is often convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^k$.  So, we can write e.g.
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k} = [x^k](1+x)^n\tag{1}
\end{align*}

Note,  this is essentially the same approach as that of @Batominovski but with a somewhat more algebraic look and feel.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}[x^k](1+x)^n[t^k](1+t)^n\tag{2}\\
> &=[x^0](1+x)^n\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^{-k}[t^k](1+t)^n\tag{3}\\
> &=[x^0](1+x)^n\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^n\tag{4}\\
> &=[x^n](1+x)^{2n}\tag{5}\\
> &=\binom{2n}{n}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we use the *coefficient of* operator twice according to (1)
- In (3) we use the *linearity* of the *coefficient of* operator and the rule $$[x^n]x^{-k}P(x)=[x^{n+k}]P(x)$$
- In (4) we use the *substitution rule* and apply $x\rightarrow \frac{1}{x}$
  \begin{align*}
  P(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k=\sum_{k=0}^nx^k[t^k]P(t)\\
  P\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)&=\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^{-k}=\sum_{k=0}^nx^{-k}[t^k]P(t)
  \end{align*}
- In (5) we use $\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^n=x^{-n}(1+x)^n$ and $[x^0]x^{-n}=[x^n]$