# Sum of squares of Binom(n,p) values

Tags: probability, summation, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

Let $x_{n,p}(j)$ be the probability that a random variable distributed according to a binomial distribution with parameters $n \in \mathbf{N}_+$ and $p \in (0,1)$ takes the value $j \in \{0,1,\ldots,n\}$, i.e.
$$x_{n,p}(j)=\binom{n}{j}p^j(1-p)^{n-j}.$$
Is it true that, independently of the value of $p$, we have that 
$$\sum_{j=0}^n x_{n,p}^2(j)=o(1)?$$

I am aware of [Vandermonde identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219928/inductive-proof-for-vandermondes-identity/219938#219938) which implies the claim holds true for $p=1/2$: indeed  $\binom{2n}{n}=\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}^2$, so that 
$$\sum_{j=0}^n x_{n,p}^2(j)=\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j}^2 \frac{1}{2^{2j}}\frac{1}{2^{2n-2j}}=\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}=O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right),$$
where the last approximation has been obtained with Stirling's formula.

Does a similar result hold in general?

Comment: Let $x$ be a probability, and $j$ denote the variable? What funny notation you use.

Comment: Ahah thank you! Anyway, I proved the answer is positive ;) Give a try

Comment: So, to use standard notation, if $X \sim Binomial(n,p)$ with pmf $f(x) = P(X=x)$, you seek the sum $$\sum_{x=0}^n {f(x)}^2 = (1-p)^{2 n} \, _2F_1\left(-n,-n;1;\frac{p^2}{(1-p)^2}\right)$$

Comment: @wolfies This particular hypergeometric function can be written in terms Legendre polynomials via [this identity](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/07/05/0001/), which may be slightly easier to stomach.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this yet?

Answer (score 2):

Put $$S_n(p)=\sum_{j=0}^n x_{n,p}^2(j).$$ My calculation evidence suggests that the sequence $\{\Delta_n\}$, where $$\Delta_n(p)=\sqrt{n} S_n(p) -\frac 1{\sqrt\pi}$$ pointwise converges on $(0,1)$ to a convex function $\Delta(p)$ such that $\Delta(1/2)=0$ and $\Delta(p)= \Delta(1-p)$ for each $p$. Any suggestions about the function $\Delta(p)$?

I add graphs of functions $\Delta_n$ suggesting the convergence:

$\Delta_{10}$:

[image]

$\Delta_{100}$:

[image]

$\Delta_{1000}$:

[image]