# Is the following combinatorial identity true? Is there any way to prove it?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

for positive integers $m$, $n$ such that $m \le n$
$${m+n \choose m} = {m \choose 0}*{n \choose 0} + {m \choose 1}*{n \choose 1} +......+ {m \choose m}*{n \choose m}$$

I was trying out some random examples and this seemed true for them. Is this equation true for all values of m and n? If yes, can it be proven?

Comment: Yes, it's Vandermonde's identity.

Comment: Thanks! You saved my day.

Comment: There most likely is a duplicate of this Question already answered here, but the one currently proposed is at best a special case.  I'd be inclined to vote to close-as-duplicate only if an *exact* duplicate target can be located.

Comment: See [Inductive Proof for Vandermonde's Identity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219928/inductive-proof-for-vandermondes-identity) for a slightly more general claim than what we have above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ${m\choose k}={m\choose m-k}$ you can write the conjectured identity as
$${m+n\choose m}=\sum_{k=0}^m{m\choose m-k}{n\choose k}\ .$$
This can be proven as follows: You can choose a team of $m$ people from $m$ boys and $n$ girls by choosing first the number $k\in[0\,..\,m]$ of girls in the team and then choose the boys in ${m\choose m-k}$ ways and the girls in ${n\choose k}$ ways.