# How does this vandermonde identity proof works?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Recently I have taken a look at this vandermonde identity proof [Inductive Proof for Vandermonde's Identity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219928/inductive-proof-for-vandermondes-identity).
\begin{align*}
  \binom{m + (n+1)}r &= \binom{m+n}r + \binom{m+n}{r-1}\\
       &= \sum_{k=0}^r \binom mk\binom n{r-k} + \sum_{k=0}^{r-1} \binom mk\binom{n}{r-1-k}\\
       &= \binom mr + \sum_{k=0}^{r-1} \binom mk\biggl(\binom n{r-k} + \binom n{r-1-k}\biggr)\\
       &= \binom mr\binom{n+1}0 + \sum_{k=0}^{r-1} \binom mk\binom{n+1}{r-k}\\
       &= \sum_{k=0}^r \binom mk \binom{n+1}{r-k}
\end{align*}

I am confused mostly at this part
\begin{align*}
  &= \sum_{k=0}^r \binom mk\binom n{r-k} + \sum_{k=0}^{r-1} \binom mk\binom{n}{r-1-k}\\
  &= \binom mr + \sum_{k=0}^{r-1} \binom mk\biggl(\binom n{r-k} + \binom n{r-1-k}\biggr)\\
\end{align*}

How did this
\begin{align*}
&= \sum_{k=0}^r \binom mk\binom n{r-k} 
\end{align*}
turn into
\begin{align*}
 &= \binom mr
\end{align*}

which identity did this person use? I am such that it could magically become C(m,r)?
I am also confused on how
\begin{align*}
\binom{n+1}0 
\end{align*}
appears in here
\begin{align*}
&= \binom mr\binom{n+1}0 + \sum_{k=0}^{r-1} \binom mk\binom{n+1}{r-k}\\
\end{align*}
If someone could help that would be very helpful, I didn't comment on the post due to it being 8 years, posted already. If someone could help and point where I should study that would be very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this step?

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^r {m \choose k}{n \choose r-k} = {m \choose r} + \sum_{k=0}^{r-1}{m\choose k}{n\choose r-k}$

Also for your second question, as $0! \equiv 1$ we'll have ${n+1\choose 0} = 1$.

Comment: yes, could please explain how did C(m,r) suddenly appear? Thank you for answering the second question

Comment: Ah, when you split off the term $k=r$ from the sum, the first coefficient is ${m\choose r}$ and the second is ${n\choose 0} = 1$. :)

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still confused as to what does split off means before hand, could you post another answer detailing the process. As I have mentioned before I lack basic knowledge of this as I searched on youtube and the internet everyone just comes with answers and no explanation. So if you could detail that process that would be a much-appreciated answer thank you.

Comment: No need for another answer! I mean that $\sum_{i=0}^2 a_i = a_2 + a_1 + a_0 = a_2 + \sum_{i=0}^1 a_i$.

Comment: Ok thanks no need to be mad about it LMAO

Comment: Not mad my friend! Just trying to help another Daniel out. :)