# Prove of Vandermonde's identity

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

I have been searched for the way of proving the following vandermonde’s identity for a long time which is far different from the original one, but I failed to find. I tried all of binomial theorem I know, and also used the way of combinatorial proof by setting several groups that has l-k indiv where m people are chosen and q+k indiv where n peole are chosen, but I have no idea where that “1” came from

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{l}{l-k\choose m}{q+k\choose n}= {l+q+1\choose m+n+1} \\(l,m,q,n >= 0)$$

How can i prove this identity? I wanna know both the combinatorial proof and the mathematical proof

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inductive Proof for Vandermonde's Identity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219928/inductive-proof-for-vandermondes-identity)

Comment: Thanks but it’s little different question. The problem he mentioned is the original form of vandermonde’s identity which k is changed in nCk, however n is changed in my question.

Comment: The identity doesn't look right to me.  E.g., if $l=q=1$ and $m=n=0$ it says that $1+1 = 3$.

Comment: OP, this is not Vandermonde's identity so shouldn't be called as such. @stange

Comment: Oh really? I thought it was Vandermonde's identity because Wikipedia said it was that

Comment: Where does Wikipedia call it that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient
it's written in the part of equation (9)

Comment: Interesting. I've not heard it called a version of Vandermonde before. Even the article on the Vandermonde identity does not mention this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, the range of your indices is wrong: it should be

$$ \sum_{k=-q}^l \binom{l-k}{m} \binom{q+k}{n} $$

Indeed, I would write $t=l+q$ so that the identity can be written simply as

$$ \sum_{r+s=t}\binom{r}{m}\binom{s}{n}=\binom{t+1}{m+n+1}. $$

This is a **generalized hockey-stick identity**. (The usual HS identity is the special case where one of $m$ or $n$ is set to $0$.) A combinatorial argument proceeds as follows:

The RHS counts how many ways there are to choose $m+n+1$ elements out of the numbers $\{1,\cdots,t+1\}$. The special thing about the "$m+n+1$" is that the numbers you picked can be categorized into three types: the smallest $m$ numbers you picked, the largest $n$ numbers you picked, and one number you picked in between the other two categories, the $(m+1)$st largest number.

The $(m+1)$st largest number you picked not only separates the numbers you picked into the $m$ smallest on one side and $n$ largest on the other, it also separates *all* of the numbers $1,\cdots,t+1$ into $r$ smaller numbers on the left and $s$ larger numbers on the right, for some pair $r,s$ with $r+s=t$. Note this means the $(m+1)$st largest number you picked is $(r+1)$.

In other words, the process of picking $m+n+1$ numbers out of $1,\cdots,t+1$ can be split into the following process: first pick the $(m+1)$st largest number $(r+1)$, then pick $m$ smaller numbers out of $1,\cdots,r$ and $n$ larger numbers out of the last $s$ numbers from $1,\cdots,t+1$.

Here is a generating function proof. By differentiating the infinite geometric series formula $m$ times and then multiplying by $(-x)^m/m!$ we arrive at the generating function:

$$ \frac{x^m}{(1-x)^{m+1}}=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\binom{r}{m}x^r. $$

Then the generalized HS identity follows from equating coefficients of $x^t$ below:

$$ \frac{x^m}{(1-x)^{m+1}}\cdot\frac{x^n}{(1-x)^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{x}\frac{x^{m+n+1}}{(1-x)^{(m+n+1)+1}}. $$

(Compare with the generating function proof of the usual Vandermonde identity.)

Comment: how can we prove it mathematically?

Comment: @jamesN I sketched a combinatorial proof in the second half of my answer. Do you want clarification or more detail, or do you mean you want a different style of proof like an algebraic proof involving generating functions or an induction proof or?

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you could give me a more detailed explanation about your combinatorial proof..I don't quite understand. Also, I wonder if it is possible to prove algebraically only by using identities involving binomial coefficients

Comment: @jamesN Sorry I had my explanation backwards. (In all my notes I put the letters $m,n$ at the top of binomial coefficients and $r,s$ on the bottom.) Fixed.

Comment: I finally understood! thanks a lot

Comment: also, do you know how to prove it algebraically or the website which proved this identity?

Comment: I added a generating function proof. Dunno where I learned these proofs.

Answer (score 2):

Here we show OPs identity is a *[Chu-Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Chu%E2%80%93Vandermonde_identity)* in disguise. The following is valid
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{k=-q+n}^{l-m}\binom{l-k}{m}\binom{q+k}{n}=\binom{l+q+1}{m+n+1}\qquad l,m,n,q\in\mathbb{N}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
where we set lower and upper limit of the sum, so that the upper index of the binomial coefficients of the summands are greater or equal the lower index, since otherwise the binomial coefficients are zero.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=-q+n}^{l-m}}&\color{blue}{\binom{l-k}{m}\binom{q+k}{n}}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{l-m+q-n}\binom{l-k+q-n}{m}\binom{k+n}{n}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{l-m+q-n}\binom{l-k+q-n}{l-k+q-n-m}\binom{k+n}{k}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{l-m+q-n}\binom{-m-1}{l-m+q-n-k}\binom{-n-1}{k}(-1)^{l+q-m-n}\tag{4}\\
> &=(-1)^{l+q-m-n}\binom{-m-n-2}{l-m+q-n}\tag{5}\\
> &=\binom{l+q+1}{l-m+q-n}\tag{6}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{l+q+1}{m+n+1}}\tag{7}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (1) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we shift the index to start with $k=0$ and compensate this by substituting in the sum $k\to k+q-n$.
- In (3) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$ twice.
- In (4) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{-p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$ twice.
- In (5) we apply the *Chu-Vandermonde identity*.
- In (6) we apply again $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{-p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (7) we apply again $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.